# Exportar clase con express

Tags: javascript, express, es6

Actualmente trabajo full scripts por ejemplo:

```
function comprobar(){
console.log('aqui el codigo');
}

exports.permitir = comprobar;
```

y necesito trabajar con clases, algo asi:

```
class Comprobador {
  function comprobar() {
    console.log('aqui el codigo');
  }
}
exports.Comprobador.permitir = Comprobador.comprobar;
```

**se puede trabajar con clases?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para exportar una [clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) en **[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/es/)** sólo tienes que utilizar [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports)

```
// comprobador.js

'use strict';

module.exports = class Comprobador {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Nueva instancia de Comprobador');
  }
  saludar(nombre) {
    console.log('Hola ' + nombre);
  }
}
```

Para importar tu [clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) debes de utilizar [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require)

```
// index.js

'use strict';

var Comprobador = require('./comprobador.js');

var c = new Comprobador();
c.saludar('hubman');
```

Comment: y del otro lado como lo obtengo?

Comment: @hubman He actualizado mi respuesta para responderte.

Comment: y si mi clase tiene una funcion con parametros, como lo uso del otro lado?

Comment: @hubman He vuelto actualizar la respuesta y te he añadido la fuente a clase para que puedas ver en detalle la creación de una clase en JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
class saludo {
  constructor() {}
  hi() {
    console.log("Hi");
  }
}

module.exports = saludo;
```

y el receptor:

```
const saludo = require("./clase"); 
var newSaludo = new saludo(); 
newSaludo.hi();
```

Comment: como puedo exportar una clase

Comment: const saludo = require("./clase");     var newSaludo = new saludo(); 
    newSaludo.hi();